# Program has stopped working dialog on close - why?

Tags: windows-vista, troubleshooting

On a variety of programs (mostly older games, but some other applications have it aswell) on Vista, when I close down the program, I see Windows "Program has stopped working" dialog, despite the fact that it has done what I told it to (i.e. Close when I clicked the Close/Exit button).

What causes this message? It seems Windows error detection is being overzealous in it's error checking.

Comment: I think that's pretty much it, vista's a bit stricter with what counts as a failed program execution. Doesn't really matter, but it IS the app's fault, and not vista's, that it's failing to close smoothly. Not that it makes any real difference :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been easier if you did specify which are these problematic programs.
Some things that you can try (one at a time) :

1. Disable all your antivirus products and anti-intrusion products.
2. Set the defaulting programs to compatibility XP SP2 (right-click on the program's file, Properties, Compatibility)
3. Add the programs that do this to the DEP list (Control Panel / System / Advanced system settings / Advanced / Performane Settings / Data Execution Prevention).

Hopefully, one of the above will solve your problem, and if not, please give more details.

Comment: I don't have the list of the apps, as it's not problematic. It's just funny, and I'm curious as to the cause.

Comment: and the event log is always a place to start your inquiries. :)

Comment: Molly is quite right, check the event log first. In any case, this problem is not really serious, it just speeds up the close ... If you find a good specimen program, just try all of the above suggestions on it.

Comment: Total Commander used to do that when Vista came out. It was subsequently fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is here: http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2009/08/12/disable-program-has-stopped-working-error-dialog-in-windows-server-2008/

(its for Win Vista and 7, too)